# java.io.IOException: Unable to unwrap data, invalid status

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, spring-security, spring-boot, single-page-application

I am working on a SPA using spring(REST backend & security) and angularjs. Everything going ok but when I run it on my local I do see an error no Idea why this is happening.

```
    2016-10-24 10:43:29.028 DEBUG 8040 --- [io-8443-exec-10] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1a572ed1:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@1b7d9385:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8443 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53170]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
10:43:29.028 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] DEBUG o.a.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1a572ed1:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@1b7d9385:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8443 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53170]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
2016-10-24 10:43:31.949 DEBUG 8040 --- [nio-8443-exec-7] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

java.io.IOException: Unable to unwrap data, invalid status [CLOSED]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.read(SecureNioChannel.java:590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1149)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:742)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:404)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:667)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

10:43:31.949 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] DEBUG o.a.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Error parsing HTTP request header
java.io.IOException: Unable to unwrap data, invalid status [CLOSED]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.read(SecureNioChannel.java:590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1149)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:742)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:404)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:667)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If anyone can give me a starting point I can do more research.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: No, my team decided to stop working on this project.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue with creating wss(secured) webscoket api using tomcat's jsr-356 and deploying over aws ec2 and referring via domain from cloudflare.
To fix the issue I made 2 changes:
- changed cloudflare proxied mode to DNS only in A record.
- Bought new certificate and started using that from tomcat instead of cloudflare's origin CA certificate.
For detailed steps check this: 
https://techxperiment.blogspot.com/2020/06/aws-ec2-tomcat-jsr-356-secure.html

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue.
It turned out that on the server side an external event was forcefully closing the connection at some point during the call, which was causing this error.